# How to programmatically get a list of used css images from IE WebBrowser (IHTMLDocument2)

Tags: html, css, twebbrowser

It is relatively straight forward to iterate through IHTMLStyleSheetsCollection, IHTMLStyleSheet, IHTMLStyleSheetRulesCollection etc. of IHTMLDocument2 to obtain list of all styles in current document.

Any ideas on how to get a list of only used styles in the document? And to be more precise, I am looking for how to find out which images from the css files are being used in the document.

There is a program that says it is able to do this (determine which css images are being used) if IE8/IE9 is installed.

Thanks

Comment: In chrome you can open the developer tools, click the audits tab, and click run to see what style rules are not being used (plus a few other things)

Comment: Thanks for tip, however I am looking for how to do this in IE WebBrowser programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found an answer to this:

Recent browser versions (FF 3.5, IE 8) have implemented a querySelector method that can be used to query if a selector is used on a page.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector for more info.